# How to scrape (extract) special characters with PHP Dom code

Tags: php, special-characters

How can I scrape contents with special characters using the following code? Currently, the code decode the special-characters and return the following.

`[&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;2&quot;&gt;1&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/span&gt;]`

```
 $url = 'http://acbar.org/ManagejobDetails.aspx?id=' . $jobid ;
   $html_dom = new simple_html_dom() ;
   $html_dom = file_get_html($url) ;
   
   
    
   foreach($html_dom->find('table [cellspacing=3] tr') as $e) {
           $children = $e->children() ;
           $size = count($children) ;
           if($size == 2) {
                   $label = $children[0]->children(0);
                   $value = $children[1]->children(0);;
                   $createXML .= createRSSFile($label,$value);
           }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

read
[`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) or [`htmlspecialchars-decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Comment: Not working. @diEcho
`$url = 'http://acbar.org/ManagejobDetails.aspx?id=' . $jobid ;
   $html_dom = new simple_html_dom() ;
   $html_dom = file_get_html($url) ;
   $a = htmlentities($html_dom);
   $b = html_entity_decode($a);




   foreach($b->find('table [cellspacing=3] tr') as $e) {
           $children = $e->children() ;
           $size = count($children) ;
           if($size == 2) {
                   $label = $children[0]->children(0);
                   $value = $children[1]->children(0);;
                   $createXML .= createRSSFile($label,$value);
           }`

Comment: @MaihanNijat : please read the first example on the links. also i have updated my answer with one more method